# How to get value of nested input hidden child into custom content using JQuery Fancybox2

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

HTML:

```
<div id="adContainer">
  <a class="iframe"  onclick="viewAd('<?=123?>')">This goes to iframe
     <input class='photo-id' type='hidden' value=123>
     <input class='photo-photo' type='hidden' value='name.jpg'>
  </a>
</div> 
<div id="adContainer">
  <a class="iframe" onclick="viewAd('<?=456?>')" >This goes to iframe
    <input class='photo-id' type='hidden' value=456>
    <input class='photo-photo' type='hidden' value='name2.jpg'>
  </a>
</div>
```

JQuery/JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.iframe").fancybox({
    'height' : '98%',
    'autoScale' : true,
    'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'fade',
    'type' : 'iframe',
    'content' : '<div class="customHTML"><h1>'+$(this).children("input.photo-id").attr("value")+'</h1><p><img src="'+$(this).children("input.photo-name").val()+'" alt="'+$(this).children("input.photo-name").val()+'"/></div>'
  });         
});


function viewAd(id){
  alert(id);
  // return "<p>Test</p>";
}
```

I can get this working for a single instance

> $("a.iframe input.photo-id").val()     //always return 123

, but when I have multiple copies of code the first one is inserted.

I have tried the following with results as a comment:

```
$(this).children("input.photo-id").attr("value")  /// Undefined
$(this).children("input.photo-id").val()        /// Undefined
$(this).children("input.photo-id").valueOf()      /// [Object object]
$(this).children("photo-id").val()              /// Undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have multiple instances of the same qualifying criteria, you need to use `$.each()` to iterate through each element to get the correct value.

```
$("a.iframe").each(function() {
  $(this).fancybox({
    'height' : '98%',
    'autoScale' : true,
    'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'fade',
    'type' : 'iframe',
    'content' : '<div class="customHTML"><h1>'+$(this).children("input.photo-id").attr("value")+'</h1><p><img src="'+$(this).children("input.photo-name").val()+'" alt="'+$(this).children("input.photo-name").val()+'"/></div>'
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I never would of got this. :)